# millis() function for PSoC4

Tags: c, timer, psoc

I'm replicating the function of `millis()` for the PSoC4 in order to store the timestamp of a signal's maximum amplitude.

For this, I'm using a timer with a 1kHz to feed the `count` terminal so it counts up each millisecond but I don't understand what clock should I use on the `clock` input.

[image]
[image]

Reading the timer component's datasheet didn't help me much

Comment: have you tried using the 1 kHz clock ? .... it is unclear what the `count` input is used for .... the count input may actually be an enable signal

Comment: PSoC Creator doesn't allow me to build the project if I try that

Comment: the IDE may have examples available

Comment: Chances are you already have some sort of systick-related millisecond function in the platform

Comment: web search for `psoc4 counter` returns this https://www.cypress.com/documentation/code-examples/ce224594-psoc-4-timercounter   ... read the first pdf

Comment: how can I look into that? @ChrisStratton